# Flutter Shows path error on take picture function

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera, flutter-dependencies, flutter-path

I write some code to take picture and saved in `getTemporaryDirectory()` path variable but wheni initalize the path on `_cameraController.takePicture(path);` it shows me error of

```
    Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found.
    Try removing the extra positional arguments. 

    await _cameraController.takePicture(path);
```

i dont get which arguments is this talking about on `path` variable please someone help me out with this error

Here is my code for taking picture:-

```
void takePhoto(BuildContext context) async{

final path = join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,"${DateTime.now()}.png");

  await _cameraController.takePicture(path);

  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder)=>CameraViewPage()));

}
```

this function will show me an error on `await _cameraController.takePicture(path);` line on `path` for `Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed`

does anyone know about this error?

Please help me,

Thank You.

Comment: The error couldn’t really be more clear. You’re passing a parameter to a method which does not accept a parameter. Please explain specifically what you don’t understand about this

Answer (score 0):

This method don't have parameters.

[`Future<XFile> takePicture()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/CameraController/takePicture.html)